# ¿Porqué devuelve resultado get_current_user_ y el resto de funciones no?

Tags: php, wordpress, error404

Estoy intentando escribir un método de envío de un formulario simple y me acabo de dar cuenta que worpress ha dejado de reconocerme funciones básicas como `get_current_user_id` o `get_user_data` etc. Decidí ir sentencia a sentencia y comprobar comandos, cuál es mi sorpresa cuando veo que al hacer la siguiente función simple, funciona, sin embargo me pongo a probar otros comandos como `get_current_user_id` (y otras muchas, `get_user` `get_user_meta` etc) y me dá error 500, el mismo error esté conectado o no el usuario con lo que.....no se que pasa....¿Me podéis...ayudar?

Funciona

```
<?php
function aver(){
$current_user = get_current_user();
echo "$current_user";}
aver ();
?>
osea que si pongo ésto (error 500)
<?php
function aver(){
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
echo "$current_user_id";}
aver ();
?>
```

P.D.: No es un plugin, comprobado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! esa funcion, bajo que contexto esta? mas que pedir ayuda y agradecer, se agradece que hagas la pregunta completa...

Comment: Gracias por responder y por la información la leeré detenidamente. Esa función no tiene ningun contexto, simplemente la hice ya desesperado  a modo de prueba para ver que "get_current_user" efectivamente funciona, no hay más. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: La funcion current_user_id solo funciona con el gancho de accion init 
add_action('init', 'myFunction');

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Jefferzon, tengo otro plugin en el mismo sitio wordpress con todas las funciones anteriormente dichas y otras más, funcionando perfectamente. Concretamente con current_user_id no tuve necesidad de usar ese gancho y funciona bien, no obstante lo acabo de probar igual y nada, error 500.

Answer (score 0):

1 semana después de muchos sudores y sangre, ya lo he resuelto. Se trataba de añadir una maldita llamada a la funcionalidad de worpress.

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('wp-blog-header.php');
```

poniendo esas 2 simpáticas líneas en la cabecera...un saludo.